# Can ffmpeg or vlc be used to stream IP camera video?

Tags: windows, ffmpeg, vlc, ip-camera

If so please provide an example.Just a simple example that doesn't refer manufacturer SDK is enough for me, I just need an example to get started, and I don't hope it to work for all cameras.

Comment: looks similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3480877/streaming-from-ip-camera-to-vlc

Answer (score 0):

Can you play your camera's video in VLC?  If so, then yes VLC can stream it.

You know, VLC's streaming documentation is quite good.  I recommend reading it.
http://www.videolan.org/doc/streaming-howto/en/

Nobody can provide an example for you because you haven't provided any information needed for such an example.  There are huge numbers of options for this project, so you are best off just reading the manual.

Comment: Never tried,IP camera needs to login to play ,can vlc or ffmpeg do this?

Comment: you may be able to write a "wrapper" that logs in and forwards the stream on to VLC...

Comment: @wamp: Yes, you can provide login data e.g. for an rstp stream via command line arguments to a vlc chain. Parameters: --rtsp-user=user --rtsp-pwd=password